# Jenkins: about the path of build.xml

Tags: jenkins

I'm getting the output below when I build a job. I have my `build.xml` in the root of my project not in `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mbp2/workspace/build.xml`... I tried to specified the path in

```
> Invoke ant:
> 
> Target: /home/javier/programacion/mbp/myfirm2/build.xml
```

but the output is the same...

I'm newbie to Jenkins and followed this [tutorial](http://jenkins-php.org/) (so I installed those plugins, maybe one of them is giving the error?).

```
Started by user anonymous
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mbp2/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@76996f0c
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision 9aafeea09cdb23317f2426f8209c75341565c070 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mbp2/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@76996f0c
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from file:///home/javier/programacion/mbp/myfirm
Seen branch in repository origin/HEAD
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Commencing build of Revision 9aafeea09cdb23317f2426f8209c75341565c070 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Checking out Revision 9aafeea09cdb23317f2426f8209c75341565c070 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here
FATAL: Unable to find build script at /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mbp2/workspace/build.xml
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any help?

Javi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Target` should be one of the ant targets (say `package`, `compile`, `test`) and **not** the location of the build file.

The build file location should be specified against `Build File`, which comes in the next line after `Target`.

Comment: Thanks, guys to see Build File you should click "Advance.."